# Insert results of DB query into a variable in controller - CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

I have two tables.

The finalists table which lists the finalists with fields such as ID, Name.
The Votes table which stores the votes for those finalists.
One row in the vote tables where the field "confirmed" is yes means one vote.

To get the number of votes for a particular finalist I run

```
$this->db->where('finalist_id', $finalist_id);
$this->db->where('confirmed', 'yes');
$query = $this->db->get('votes');
return $query->num_rows();
```

And that gets me the number of rows.(votes)

Now what I want to do is loop through my finalists and list their name, their ID and their number of votes but I am struggling to write the code in my controller.

My controller :

```
$this->load->database();

            $query = $this->db->get('finalists');
            $data['finalists'] = $query->result_array();


                $this->db->where('finalist_id', $finalist->id);
                $this->db->where('confirmed', 'yes');
                $query = $this->db->get('votes')
                $data['votes'] = $query->result_array();


    $this->template
            ->build('admin/listing', $data);
```

My view:

```
<?php foreach ($finalists as $finalist): ?>



<li>ID:<?php echo $finalist['id'] ?>, Name:<?php echo $finalist['name'] ?>, votes:<?php echo $finalist['votes'] ?></li>


<?php endforeach ?>
```

SO what I am trying  to achieve is to add the key vote and its result to the array $finalists - obviously to the right one, and I can't get my head around how to do that.

I suppose I should loop through the finalists and somehow insert the result of the query for that particular finalist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to loop and make a query for every finalist. What you need to learn how to do is use table `JOIN` and the `SUM()` function in conjunction with `GROUP BY`. This can allow you to get your entire result set in a single query. Though I don't use codeigniter, I am sure there is documentation out there on how to do this.

Comment: The thing is that the data I need from one of the tables is only the number of rows returned by a particular query. I think you're right that it must be possible in a single query but I have no idea how. I thought about looping through the results of the finalists query and query the number of rows for each ID so it can be pushed into the $data array along with the finalists other details.

Comment: Work on the raw SQL query first, then you can figure out how to implement in codeigniter second. You have to have an understanding of the join first. Something like `SELECT f.id, f.name, COUNT(v.confirmed) AS votes FROM finalists AS f INNER JOIN votes AS v on f.id = v.finalist_id WHERE v.confirmed = 'yes' GROUP BY f.id` should get you started.

Comment: This link should give you a better idea as to how to form more complex queries using codeigniter's ActiveRecord class.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Hey Mike, that worked great thank you. Any way of grouping by vote ? I tried but it says there is no such column... Do you want to put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the right answer ?

Comment: I added answer below.  I am not sure what you mean about wanting to group by votes.  If you mean the `COUNT(v.confirmed) AS votes` I don't understand what you gain, as this column itself is an aggregation.  Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I meant SORT BY. I got it to work thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work on the raw SQL query first, then you can figure out how to implement in codeigniter second. You have to have an understanding of the join first. Something like this should get you started:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, COUNT(v.confirmed) AS votes
FROM finalists AS f
INNER JOIN votes AS v
  ON f.id = v.finalist_id
WHERE v.confirmed = 'yes'
GROUP BY f.id
```

This link should give you a better idea as to how to form more complex queries using codeigniter's ActiveRecord class. ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this into your controller

```
   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('finalists');
   $this->db->join('votes',finalists.id = votes.finalist_id);
   $this->db->where('votes.confirmed', 'yes');

   $query = $this->db->get();
   $data['finalists'] = $query;


   $this->template->build('admin/listing', $data);
```

and this will your view

```
<?php foreach ($finalists->result() as $finalist){ ?>



<li>ID:<?php echo $finalist->id; ?>, Name:<?php echo $finalist->name; ?>, votes:<?php echo $finalist->votes; ?></li>


<?php } ?>
```

### UPDATE

Comment: Can't use $finalist->id as it doesn't refer to anything

Comment: $finalist->id is contain your id because i m now using result() in foreach

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: finalist - Trying to get property of non-object - Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: ok then tell me what is your Primary key of `finalists` table?

Comment: the primary key is "id"